# Ruby on Rails first_or_create nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Place Model:

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_places, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, through: :post_places
end
```

Post Model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_places, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :places, through: :post_places, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :places,
                                :allow_destroy => true,
                                :reject_if     => :all_blank

end
```

Post Create:

```
 def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Post Params:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :user_id, places_attributes: [:id, :title, :latitude, :longitude, :_destroy])
end
```

When registering a new post, I want it not to re-register and use that id if it is registered in the database.I found this code to do this, but it does not accept it because it is a nested attribute.

The code Im using in Place create:

```
@place = Place.where(latitude: place_params[:latitude], longitude: place_params[:longitude]).first_or_create do |place|
  place.attributes = place_params
end
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What you want is "If an existing post is submitted, I want to associate it to a new place, instead of creating both?"

Comment: if an existing place submitted, i want to associated with post but if not exists create a new place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description saying

*"If an existing place submitted, i want to associated with post but if not exists create a new place."*

Your requirement is something like this, check this answer and tel me if you need something like this. So that we can proceed further.

```
@place = Place.where(latitude: place_params[:latitude], longitude: place_params[:longitude])

if @place.present? // if place exist
    @post.places << @place // push that to existing post
else
    @place = Place.new(latitude: place_params[:latitude], longitude: place_params[:longitude]) 
    if @place.save // else create a place
        @post.places << @place // push that to post
    end   
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
1-) More than one place can be selected while creating a post. Can the code you write do this?
2-) Place comes in post parameter I need to write it directly in the post create section?

Comment: yes you can assign any number of places to the post, `@post.places << @place` , this keeps on adding places to respective post.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to tweak it a bit, I think is something like this

```
  #will yield the place, or a new one will be initialized                    
  @place = Place.where(latitude: place_params[:latitude], longitude: place_params[:longitude]).first_or_initialize(place_params)
  #find associated post
  @post = Post.find(post_params)
  #add to collection
  @place.posts << @post

  if @place.valid?
    @place.save
  end
```

if you want it the other way around

```
  @post.places << @place
```

I am not sure about 'Post.find', I think you are missing Post.id in your params

Comment: Do I need to write this code while the post is being created or do I need to write while creating the place?

Comment: It should be when you create a new place, specifically, in your places controller's create action.